# SQL convert getdate() to string with timestamp

Tags: sql, date

Hi is  it possible to return the getdate() in a string with the timestamp

```
SELECT 'Date data collected ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE())
```

which will return, Date data collected Dec 10 2014

but would like to have "Date data collected 2014-12-10 12:03:22.713"

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the 121 option in SQL-Server:

```
select 'Date data collected ' +convert(varchar,convert(datetime,getdate(),121))
```

full details of all date conversion options are in the transact-sql books, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Hi, getting the following error msg Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Syntax error converting datetime from character string.

Comment: Has to be converted to a varchar to concatenate them together.  If you just wanted to see the date it would be:

    select convert(datetime,getdate(),121)